# How do I join two dataframes on Boolean and return the inverse

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas `itertuples` method to perform row matching between two dataframes (df-A & df-B). The result is a copy of df-B with only the passed results.

df-B before:

```
   B   Y
0  2  10
1  4  15
2  6  15
```

df-B after (as df-B2):

```
   B   Y     e
0  2  10  True
1  6  15  True
```

How can I compare df-B and df-B2 and return only the missing (implied False) rows?

```
   B   Y
1  4  15
```

Comment: PS. I've tried various ways to get the T/F into the resulting df-B2; however, the way I've iterated over the two df the result clobbers the original df or produces erroneous rows. The current solution works, except for returning the missing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the excellent [Pandas Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) and I think it will do what you want:

```
pd.merge(df-B, df-B2, how='outer',
    indicator=True)
    .query('_merge == "left_only"')
    .drop(['_merge'],axis=1)
```

This is a way to get rows that appear in df-B that don't appear in df-B2.

Comment: +1, that worked. Now I'm going to move from the toy to the real data and marked answered whichever returns the correct df! TY

Answer (score 1):

Use `~` for inverse of mask:

```
df-B[~df-B.e]
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) is more general because it check index and column values too. So column `Y` is set to index and then get mask. Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df1)
    B   Y
0  2  10
1  4  15
2  6  15

print (df2)
   B   Y     e
0  2  10  True
2  6  15  True

df11 = df1.set_index('B')[['Y']]
df22 = df2.set_index('B')[['Y']]
mask = df11.isin(df22).reset_index()
print (mask)
   B      Y
0  2   True
1  4  False
2  6   True

print (df1[mask.Y])
   B   Y
0  2  10
2  6  15

print (df1[~mask.Y])
   B   Y
1  4  15
```

Comment: I don't have df2. That's the result I want.

Comment: +1, that worked. Now I'm going to move from the toy to the real data and marked answered whichever returns the correct df! TY

Comment: Sure, I think you get same outputs (if not duplicates). But if larger df, `isin` solution is faster,

Comment: You say "duplicates"; Is this a limitation of this method? My real data does have duplicates. I set the column of `pd.datetime`s to the index, and `isin` kicked an error, "ValueError: cannot compute isin with a duplicate axis." Checking the dataset with `df[df.index.duplicated()]` there are indeed duplicate timestamps.

Comment: I hope my solution can works with duplicates nice, but it seems not. `Merge` solution have same problem, I guess. So need remove duplicates. :(

Comment: Actually, `merge` solution did produce **something**, whereas the `isin` had the `ValueError`. The final result was a 44 line subset of 53 line df, which was a **reasonable** result. I'm continuing to validate the results now. Thanks for your prompt answer, and look forward to learning this Pandas pattern of mask-isin as I learn more about Pandas.